# How is the element passed into the callback method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, callback

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I am slightly confused as to how the callback function for the `Array.find()` method works,

I have this current code:

```
const numbers= [43,46,33,23,44,36,5]

function under50(num) {
    return num < 50;
}

val = numbers.find(under50);
```

According to the Mozilla Docs:

callback
Function to execute on each value in the array, taking three arguments:

**element**

The current element being processed in the array.

**Index**

The index of the current element being processed in the array.

**Array**

The array find was called upon.

Now in understand the method I am passing the element, this is then being iterated over, and as soon as an element in found it will return the value. However, what confuses me, is how does it know the element when I have never explicitly passed the method the Array? If someone could post a simplistic example, it would be really helpful

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have never explicitly passed the method the Array"*? It's right there: `numbers.find`. This is `Array.prototype.find`, where `Array` is your array (`numbers`).

Comment: You are calling `find()` *on* the array, so it knows what the array is. You posted a working example — what other kind of example are you looking for?

Comment: exactly you indicates yourself to the callback function what is the element onto proceed, here, your _numbers_ array

Comment: The *effective* result of calling `.find()` on the array is the following `for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { if (callback(numbers[i], i, numbers)) return numbers[i] }` - however you shouldn't assume the JS engine simply replaces it with that - it doesn't necessarily. However, whatever it does, it will achieve the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @GerardoFurtado's comment, the value of `this` inside the `.find()` method gets set to your array. So it has both the array and the callback function. It then basically creates the equivalent of a typical `for` loop, and invokes your callback in that loop, passing each member.

To give a simple example, make your own `.find()` method.

```js
// Be careful extending native prototypes
Array.prototype.myFind = function(callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (callback(this[i], i, this)) {
      return this[i]; // callback result was "truthy" so return this item
    }
  }

  return undefined; // not found, so return undefined
}

const numbers = [43,46,33,23,44,36,5]

function under50(num) {
    return num < 50;
}

const val = numbers.myFind(under50);

console.log(val);
```

This is quite simplified, and does not exhibit all the same behavior as the standard method, but is enough to show how to use `this` as a reference to the object on which the method was invoked.

For completeness, you may ask how JavaScript knows that your array has a property (a method in this case) named `find`. Obviously, it doesn't. But JavasCript will look for `find` in the prototype chain. Have a look:

```js
const numbers= [43,46,33,23,44,36,5];
console.log("find" in numbers)
```

Comment: You can also put this in your answer, to show that the property is looked at the prototype chain: https://jsfiddle.net/8s0Ljbhh/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: I made it a community wiki, so please feel free to make improvements.

Comment: This has been a really helpful and inciteful answer, thanks so much!